# How to use module.exports properly in node.js?

Tags: node.js

So I am trying to pass data from one node.js script to another node.js script properly and I'm having some bugs I can not find easy fixes ...

So here is the file that is supposed to pass the data:

```
//main.js    
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function input() {
    exec('ruby user_zipcode.rb', function (err,stdout) {
        if (err) {
            throw (err)
        } else {
            var input = stdout;

            console.log(input)
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {'Data':input()};
```

and the other file that is supposed to received the data:

```
//wawa.js    
var test = require('./main');

console.log(test.Data);
```

The main.js execute a child process with this simple ruby file :

```
//user_zipcode.rb    
data = '78456'
puts data
```

and I got this when I run `node wawa.js` I have this result :

```
undefined
78456
```

I do not understand where the `undefined` come from and how to fix the problem.

Please help !!!

Comment: `console.log(test.Data);` is your `undefined`, `console.log(input)` is `78456` -- what do you think `test.Data` should returns instead?

Comment: @Federkun honestly I have no idea .. I'm still learning. What is the correct way to use "var input = stdout;"  from "wawa.js" ? I am still struggling with the whole import-export thing

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `undefined` is coming from this statement:

```
console.log(test.Data);
```

`input()` doesn't explicity returns nothing, so `undefined` is what you see there.

The `console.log(input)` is where you see that `78456`.

About

> how to fix the problem

I'll assume that you want `test.Data` to return the output of your ruby script. `input()` could simply return a promise,

```
//main.js    
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function input() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        exec('ruby user_zipcode.rb', function (err,stdout) {
            if (err) {
                return rej(err)
            }

            return res(stdout)
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    "Data": input() // this now returns a Promise
};
```

then

```
//wawa.js    
var test = require('./main');

test.Data.then(console.log)
```

Comment: Note that depending on which version of node. The `.log` method of the console object refers to `this` internally. Therefore `foo.then(console.log)` will not work. The proper way to do it is `foo.then(x -> console.log(x))`. It should be noted that while for node.js this depends on version, this is true for all versions of all browsers